# how set value to null in emojiable textarea using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having problem with my textarea which i set emojiable to true, i try to empty texatrea value after form has been submit, but it is not working but once i set emojiable to false it will start working properly, i have being trying to work it out, but i don't know if the problem is from my code or the emoji plugin am using.

```
  //this my form with textarea 
<form class="p-comment-f" method="post" id="p-comment-f3" >
<label for="p-comment-file3" 
style="diplay:none;"><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></label>
<textarea placeholder="Type a comment" class="p-comment-f-i" name="comment" id="p-comment-f-i3" 
 data-emojiable="true" data-emoji-input="unicode"></textarea>
  <input type="hidden" name="rand">
  <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="3">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="send" class="post-info-btn">
  </form>


//this my jquery

$(document).on("click",".post-info-btn",function(event){
 event.preventDefault();

  var txt = $(this).siblings("textarea").val();
  txt = txt.trim();
  var p = $(this).siblings("input[name=post_id]").val();
  var id = $(this).parent("form").attr("id");
  var ran = randomString(20);
  var pg_status = $("#g_search_f").children("input[type=hidden]").val();
  var pg_txt = getPath();

  $(this).siblings("input[name=rand]").val(ran);

     if ( txt !=""){

           var i_id =  $("#"+id).children("textarea").attr("id");
           $("textarea").val("");
                //fastComment(p,txt,ran,pg_txt);


    }

   });
```

Comment: Hi hacker. Whats the emoji plugin you're using?

Comment: am using emoji picker

Comment: Is it this one here?: https://github.com/OneSignal/emoji-picker/blob/master/README.md if so, scroll down to the section "what happens under the hood". It looks like a contenteditable div is created beside each textarea where data-emojiable=true and the original textarea is hidden. So in order to clear the visible "textarea" i think u will have to target the div that is created and set the innerHTML of the div to "". If i was you i would log your HTML to the console to try see the  contenteditable div and go from there. I can help you more tomorrow but i gotta sleep now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The emoji-picker plugin adds a contenteditable div after each textarea/input field where `data-emojiable=true` and the original textarea/input field is hidden. (This div will contain img tags of the selected emojis and text.).

So in order to clear the text in the visible "`textarea`" you will have to target the div that is created and set the `innerHTML` of the div to `""`. You can do this with `jQuery` as follows:

```
$("textarea").next("div").html("");
```

I also discovered that if you have a class on your textarea/input field this class will also be added to the div (that is created by emoji-picker).

So as you have a class called `p-comment-f-i` on your textarea then you can target the div more precisely as follows:

```
$("textarea").next("div.p-comment-f-i").html("");
```

You can test that you are targeting the right element by outputting text to the area as follows:

```
$("textarea").next("div.p-comment-f-i").html("Test my emoji textarea");
```

Note: Make sure you also clear the hidden textarea/input field as you were doing (as this will still contain the text and unicode values of the emojis that were selected)

```
$("textarea").val("");
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thats great ! No probs :)